# Taking input for a VBA script

Tags: excel, vba

I've a vba script which emails certain cell range values to particular people. but the problem is I've to edit the body of email every time I need to change something. Is there a way in which I can add a field like : "Enter the email address=" and I could enter the email and the script in the back end take that mail address and I'll be able to send it.

```
Set CH = ActiveChart CH.Parent.Name = "Rishab" 

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Rishab").Height = RNG.Height 
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Rishab").Width = RNG.Width 

RNG.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap CH.Paste CH.Export "P:\ABC.png" 

esubject = "Shift Handover_Night" 
sendto = "ISHelpdeskTeam@appvion.com" 

Set app = CreateObject("outlook.application") 
Set itm = app.CreateItem(0) 

With itm 
    .Subject = esubject 
    .To = sendto 
    .CC = ccto 
    .HTMLBody = "<img src='P:\ABC.png'/> <br> <br> Thank You <br> Regards <br> Helpdesk" 
    .Display 
    .send 
End With 

Set app = Nothing 
Set itm = Nothing
```

Comment: Please include your coding attempts and research and explain what isn't working.

Comment: Below is the script that I am using, it'll take a screenshot of the certain excel range and then it'll email it. Suppose I want an option which will say enter email address and it'll ask us to enter what you want to include in the body of the email.

Comment: Set CH = ActiveChart CH.Parent.Name = "Rishab"
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Rishab").Height = RNG.Height
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Rishab").Width = RNG.Width
RNG.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap
CH.Paste CH.Export "P:\ABC.png"
esubject = "Shift Handover_Night"
sendto = "ISHelpdeskTeam@appvion.com"
Set app = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set itm = app.CreateItem(0)
With itm .Subject = esubject .To = sendto .CC = ccto
.HTMLBody = "<img src='P:\ABC.png'/> <br> <br> Thank You <br> Regards <br> Helpdesk"
.Display .send End With Set app = Nothing Set itm = Nothing ende:

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. After inserting the code, highlight all the code and press Ctrl + K to enter between code tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an input box to prompt the user.

```
EmailAddress = InputBox("Enter the email address")
```

Comment: esubject = "abc"
sendto = "abc@abc.com"



Set app = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set itm = app.CreateItem(0)

With itm
.Subject = esubject
.To = sendto
.CC = ccto
.HTMLBody = "<img src='P:\ABC.png'/> <br> <br> Thank You <br> Regards <br> abc"
.Display
.send
End With
Set app = Nothing
Set itm = Nothing

Comment: let's suppose this is my script, then how to take the input in excel

Comment: sendto = InputBox("Enter the email address")